# Removing a "sample.ext.ext2" file that has no "sample.ext" file associated with it

Tags: windows, file, batch-file, cmd

The application creates `.mta` files (with exactly same name) of all multimedia files in my HDD. What I want to do is to check all sub-folders of root folder if there is no multimedia file associated with some `.mta` then delete it.

**Detailed example. Lets say we have files**

```
01.mp3
01.MP3.mta
02.mkv
02.MKV.mta
03.jpg
03.JPG.mta
04.MP4.mta     <<==
```

As you see the last `.mta` has no original file. I want to delete last file.

I don't know if it's possible with cmd. But following function doesn't work. Please take a look

```
For /r %%i in (*.mta) do call :nomta %%i
pause

goto end

:nomta
set stem=%1:.mta=%

set original=%stem%.mta
if not exist %original% do exit /B
if not exist %stem% do del /a /Q  %1

goto :EOF 

:end

echo done
PAUSE
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a for command to do this with `dir /a` feeding it both hidden and non-hidden filenames. Here's an example:

```
C:\temp\z\z>attrib *
A            C:\temp\z\z\foo.bar.mta
A   H        C:\temp\z\z\h2.mp4.mta
A            C:\temp\z\z\hid.mp4
A   H        C:\temp\z\z\hid.mp4.mta
A            C:\temp\z\z\zoo.bar
A            C:\temp\z\z\zoo.bar.mta

C:\temp\z\z>for /f %F in ('dir /b/a *.mta') do if not exist "%~nF" echo %F >> z

C:\temp\z\z>type z
foo.bar.mta
h2.mp4.mta
```

so replacing the echo with a del should achieve your target.